# Malicious Autoit v3 shortcuts

Tags: autoit, explorer, virus

My pc got infected from an external usb and a lot of files with the extension of .lnk got into my hard drive as a shortcuts with that target

C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c start ..\Microsoft\MicrosoftSecurity.exe  /AutoIt3ExecuteScript  ..\Microsoft\Microsoft.a3x explorer  String("%") & ChrW(10+57) & String("D") & String("%")  & exit

I just want to know what does this do and means.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It executes the (compressed) script `Microsoft.a3x` with `MicrosoftSecurity.exe` (which has to be a compiled AutoIt script to be able to do this) and passes `explorer %CD%` as a parameter. Afaik, Microsoft doesn't use AutoIt, plus there is some code obfuscation involved, so I doubt, it's meant to do something good. Hard to tell what it really does, without seeing the source code of `microsoft.a3x`. The whole thing looks highly suspicious to me.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I did a full scan after I copied the shortcut target and permanently deleted the file so I can't get hold of the code but I'll try to.
This link my explain more, it details a lot of what happened like the virus behavior, registry, shortcuts and executable files.
https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/threat-encyclopedia/malware/worm.autoit.otorun.ac
Thanks again.